# It´s possible to delete some revisions that I have done?

Tags: support, editing

It´s possible to delete some revisions that I have done? I would like to know about this because I consider some steps unnecessary.

Comment: yes, if you click on the edit link below your post, you should be able roll back?

Comment: Thanks but this command I know. I would like a way to eliminate steps from the historic.

Comment: I am a fussy twiddler and often guilty of excessive incremental editing of my answers. Makes for a messy editing history, I'm sure. But to whom does it matter? So far no one has complained. I don't let it bother me and neither should you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the only provision for actually eliminating a revision from the edit history is in the case where confidential information was accidentally or maliciously posted.  "Unnecessary steps" are surely not justification for this sort of administrative action.